# wordpress tools not showing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've inherited some WP project and can't see Tools in WP Dashboard. I've got Admin privileges, so checked my user db settings. Does anyone know where it could be restricted either in db or some config. I've installed latest WP version but keep old db & theme.

Thanks,

Comment: Try activating the default theme, and then check.
If that does not fixes it, try disabling the plugins one by one and checking as you do them.

Comment: are you sure you have admin privileges? I inherited a project once where they used a plugin for users/roles and they gave me an admin account that was actually not everything I needed.  In the db, there might be one account with actual Administrator privileges, usually user with id=1

Comment: Yeah, I do. I've deactivated all plugins and nothing's changed.

Comment: I've deactivated theme and all seems to be ok on WP default themes.

Comment: It's been restricted somewhere in the theme I guess.

Comment: It's been in functions.php remove_menu_page('tools.php')